# Sprites and collision detection cocos2d android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, collision, sprite, overlapping

I just have a short question!
I make an app where random sprites drawen on the screen, and i want that these sprites dont overlaps for the others.(these sprites are the same picture but the positions are random only)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a sprite intersect another one you can use

```
CCSprite *sprite1, *sprite2;
if (CGRectIntersectRect(sprite1.boundingBox, sprite2.boundingBox)) {
  // sprites are overlapping
}
```

This doesn't take into account rotation as calculations would become far more complicated.

I don't understand if you want to deploy an amount of sprites with no overlaps, in this case a fair trivial approach is the following:

```
CCNode *parent;
for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; ++i) {
  CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWith..];
  bool isOk = false;
  while (!isOk) {
    sprite.position = ccp(...);
    isOk = true;
    for (CCSprite *sprite2 in parent) {
      if (CGRectIntersectRect(sprite.boundingBox, sprite2.boundingBox)) {
        isOk = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i only got 1 sprite and when im touching the screen this sprites comes out again but with a differenet position (for example the will be 2 "smiling sun" in the screen)so i want to compare only 1 sprite couse only 1 sprite created but added as child again and again with different positions.

Comment: Then it's even simpler than this since you don't need the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList to save the previous sprite(sun)location and can apply check when you are adding new sun

```
ArrayList<CGRect> sunArrayList=new ArrayList<CGRect>();
```

now apply the check when you generate the new sprite(sun) on screen

```
boolean exist;// variable to check position already exist
do{
    exist=false; //set at every loop starting new no generated not exist we have to check this below. if exist change it to true
    //generate no
    int xRandom=3;//apply your logic for random location x
    int yRandom=5;//apply your logic for random location y

for(int i=0;i<sunArrayList.size();i++)
{
    if(sunArrayList.get(i).contains(xRandom,yRandom))
    {
        exist=true;
    }
}

    if(exist==false)// means your generated location not exist
    {
        // add sun to screen with position xRandom,yRandom
        //write code here to add sprite on screen (xRandom,yRandom)

        ///
        CGSize sunSize=CGSize.make(width, height);
        //CGSizeSunSize=sprite(sun) slicing size 

CGPoint sunPos=new CGPoint();
        sunPos.set(xRandom, yRandom);
CGRect randomLocationGeneratedSun=new CGRect(sunPos,sunSize);
sunArrayList.add(randomLocationGeneratedSun);
    }

}while(exist)
```